# How to send params in compose method of mailer yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I'm trying to send one param ($id) to view `layout\html.php` using `compose()` method of mailer component. But i don't know how to get it

The code:

```
$id = 1;
Yii::$app->mailer->compose('\layouts\html.php', ['id' => $id])
->setFrom('stackfrom@gmail.com')
->setTo('stackto@gmail.com')
->setSubject('Email sent from Yii2-Swiftmailer')
->send();
```

And in a line of my view layout\html.php

`<div><?php echo $id ?></div>`

[Error is here!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsb5d.png)

Comment: update the question and show the error message  too

Comment: without the error...cannot resolve

Comment: I need 10 of reputation for embed images! error in link called: "Error is here!" just below `<div><?php echo $id ?></div>` code !

Comment: posted an answer for you see if that helps you out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't call a view file with `compose()` method like this, you should use `alias` like `@common`, `@frontend` or any other relevant to the view you are trying to load mostly we place all views related to emails in `common/mail` so we will use `@common` alias in example.

You can use 2 ways

1. You may pass additional view parameters to `compose()` method, which will be available inside the view files.`Yii::$app->mailer->compose('@common/path/to/view', ['id' => $id]);`
2. Render `HTML` separately

`$body =Yii::$app->view->renderFile('@common/path/to/view-file.php',['id'=>$id])`

to render the `HTML` from the `php` file, pass it any parameters you want to like any normal view file and then attach it to the email body using `setHtmlBody($body)`, use the following way

```
$body = Yii::$app->view->renderFile ( '@common/mail/account-activation.php' , [
    'id' => $id 
        ] );

Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
->setFrom('stackfrom@gmail.com')
->setTo('stackto@gmail.com')
->setSubject('Email sent from Yii2-Swiftmailer')
->setHtmlBody($body)
->send()
```

For more help see [Documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-mailing.html#composing-mail-content)

Comment: It really works!! But i was asking about how to get params in view from `compose()` method.
Anyway i was using:

`Yii::$app->view->param['id'] = $id` 

....And then, in `layouts\html.php` view:

`<div><?php echo Yii::$app->view->param['id'] ?></div>` then, this works perfectly in a sent email too.

Thanks so much for your time and for answering me !!!

Comment: @Monic `Yii::$app->mailer->compose('@common/path/to/view', ['id' => $id]);` is the way to get the param in view that you are loading , use alias to provide path to the view in compose , what is the full path to your view from the root of your project?

Comment: Good explain and it works!!! then i go to use the 2º way for send params. Thanks for answering me!

Comment: @Monic I also use the 2nd one mostly :P it looks easier and the view part can be managed separately, good luck and do mark the answer as correct if it worked for you

Comment: i'm using  ` '@app/mail/layouts/html.php'` then as I told you, it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Compose method takes special alias in format '@app/mail/layouts/default.php'
So if you are using absolute format, use @ and path (yii2 aliases)

Reference to swift mailer you can see here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-swiftmailer-mailer.html

Comment: Using `Yii::$app->mailer->compose('\layouts\html.php');`, Email sends correctly. But i need get params in that view using `Yii::$app->mailer->compose('\layouts\html.php', ['id' => $id])`.

In reference guide to swift mailer i havent find anything about get params in view using `mailer->compose()`. Thanks in advance